# How to do a string replace with only the decimal digits and remove exceptions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data frame with different columns and values.

Column1 [1,000,00;100,00;10,00]

I need to replace comas to dot just before the last two digits, but I would also need to remove the coma whenever its not located as a decimal on the column.

Column1 [1000.00;100.00;10.00]

Comment: If this is really your data, use two passes. The first would be a regex with a lookahead for 2 digits after the comma, substitute a full stop. Then, remove all remaining commas.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.replace` to remove all comma and dot, cast to float and divide by 100 (assumption: you have only two decimal points?)

```
>>> df['A'].str.replace(r'[,.]', '', regex=True).astype(float) / 100

0    1000.0
1     100.0
2      10.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to import the csv files and define the parameter:

df = pd.read_csv(file, thousands='.', decimal=',')